# Getting data attributes from HTML option tag via event.target - using dataset or getAttribute does not work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React application in which I have a `select` tag with children `option` tags. For each `option` tag, I am passing some extra data that I want associated with each option and eventually retrieved to be passed into other helper functions.

```
const MyDropdown = () => {
    const _onChange = e => {
        // Here, I want to get the data attribute data-otherData and pass it into a function call.
        console.log(e.target.dataset.otherData) // returns undefined
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-otherData") // returns null
    }

    return (
        <select onChange={_onChange}>
            <option value="USA" data-otherData="selectLocation_US">I live in USA</option>
            <option value="CA" data-otherData="selectLocation_CA">I live in Canada</option>
            <option value="UK" data-otherData="selectLocation_UK">I live in UK</option>
            <option value="AU" data-otherData="selectLocation_AU">I live in Australia</option>
        </select>
    )
}
```

By doing various searches on the Web, I determined that I should either do `event.target.dataset.otherData` or `event.target.getAttribute("data-otherData")` in order to access my data attributes. However, none of those work.

Does anyone know what my issue is?

EDIT: I've created a fiddle to show what is happening: https://jsfiddle.net/mp8ns90o/

It was pointed out to me that the data attributes should be in kebab case and accesses to `dataset` should be in camelCase.

So, I've tried:
I live in USA

and tried to retrieve it by using `e.target.dataset.otherData` and `e.target.getAttribute('data-other-data')` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the dropdown exists at the time that you are attempting to gain access to it?

Comment: I believe so. I'm manually clicking the option in the dropdown in order to trigger the `onChange` event and expecting to retrieve the unique data but not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `camelCase` in JavaScript to look up the value in the `dataset`, it will look actually look for those words in `kebabcase`. I.E. `data-other-data`.

> To get a data attribute through the dataset object, get the property by the part of the attribute name after data- (note that dashes are converted to camelCase).

The easiest option would be to fix your naming convention in the markup to conform.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```js
const article = document.querySelector('#electric-cars');

console.log(article.dataset.columns) // "3"
console.log(article.dataset.indexNumber) // "12314"
console.log(article.dataset.parent) // "cars
```

```html
<article
  id="electric-cars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

This behavior is consistent throughout the browser API. For example If you want to set an elements `border-width`, you use the `camelCase` form `element.style.borderWidth`

Furthermore, you need to grab the option manually. This is because your event target is always the select and not the option itself.

```js
const onChangeHandler = ({target}) => {
    let lbl = target
      .querySelector(`option[value="${target.value}"]`)
      .dataset
      .eventLabel
    console.log(lbl);     
}
```

fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ngx1p0t/

Comment: That's a good point so I just tried that and it doesn't work either. I've created a fiddle to show what is happening and edited my original post. https://jsfiddle.net/mp8ns90o/

Comment: I know whats wrong though. See you trigger the event always on the select and the options set its value but they dont set its dataset. So you always hav as event target the select and not the option. You need to grab the option manually in the callback.

Comment: D'oh! That was it. Thanks for helping me out on that.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
const options = {
    USA: {
        location: 'selectLocation_US',
        label: 'I live in USA',
    },
    CA: {
        location: 'selectLocation_CA',
        label: 'I live in Canada',
    },
    UK: {
        location: 'selectLocation_UK',
        label: 'I live in UK',
    },
    AU: {
        location: 'selectLocation_AU',
        label: 'I live in Australia',
    }
}

const _onChange = e => {
    console.log(options[e.target.value].location)
}

const MyDropdown = () => {
    return (
        <select onChange={_onChange}>
            {
                Object.entries(options).map(([k, v]) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={k}>{v.label}</option>
                    )
                })
            }
        </select>
    )
}

return MyDropdown()
```